# Analysing three-directional relationships

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

Suppose there are three variables A, B and C, that are thought to have a three-directional relationship. This means A is related to B and C, B also influences A and C, and C affects A and B.

I wondered which analytic approaches could be taken to assess this complex relationship? I can think of

- multiple regression, f.i., A ~ B + C.
- Mediation analysis if we believe that B moderates the influence of A on C (f.i., A and C are behaviours, while B is an endogeneous factor).